# Change model building mapbox in unit3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I have got data from mapbox to create map in unity. When it comes to changing buildings, I don't know how to handle it.
Currently I want to change the model for the buildings.
Kind of like creating a list of prefabs and then replacing the existing buildings.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit of a large question. But [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-map-in-unity/) explains how to customize the look of the 3D buildings.

Comment: is there a way to change the model of the buildings in the map?

Comment: well, you can change the look of the buildings like explained in the tutorial I linked. Do you want to display meshes other than the ones provided by mapbox?

Comment: Yes, What I have to do

Comment: You will have to implement a custom solution then. That's complicated and to broad of a question for Stackoverflow.